# Javascript click button start with name

Tags: javascript, jquery

can i change this button click

```
$('input[name="submit.one-click-premium-de.x"]').click().first();
```

to a button that has a wild card after first words?

```
$('input[name="submit.one-click*"]').click().first();
```

or something?

When the Button Name start with submit.one-click i will click this.

All things after "one-click" is okay. So i want like a wildcard there...
My click on top works but i want to have a start with one-click button... 
I tried much strange things but thats not working

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate of the one linked above, and while you're not using the ID, the same syntax in the answer holds.

Answer (score 3):

`^=` is the startsWith selector:

```
$('input[name^="submit.one-click"]').click().first();
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use ^= to do this. It works this way:

```
$('input[name^="submit.one-click"]').click().first();
```